# Куки на машине пользователя

Tags: php, cookie

Вопрос в следующем, допустим я делаю авторизацию пользователя на сайте и в случае успешной авторизации устанавливаю куки (setcookie('auth','yes',time()+3600);).
данная кука например открывает доступ к закрытой части сайта. Так вот, можно ли с машины пользователя самому создать куки и обойти это ограничение?

Comment: Такую простую куку можно создать самому без каких-либо ухищрений.

Comment: В основном используют произвольную сточку которая привязывается к сессии пользователя, и записываем в cookie, как-то так `setcookie('auth','dbd4d5171a44361bc4d122f256e7c555',time()+3600);`, но я хочу скорее сказать что cookie хранятся в браузере пользователя и это нужно учитывать, что пользователь может изменить cookie или создать новую и доверять cookie нельзя, в общем как всему что отправляет пользователь!!!

Comment: Вообще я бы посоветовал начать изучения с Web Framework'a допустим https://laravel.com/, почитать документацию и изучить его, просто он за вас будет заботится о авторизованных пользователях и какие станицы ему не стоит показывать

Comment: @users, круто :) Чтобы поставить безопасно куку, нужно изучить/воспользоваться laravel!

Comment: Да, можно. Лучше использовать сессию

Comment: @Visman по мне так сейчас лучше изучить laravel и быть уверенным что он превратит печенье в нечитабельную кашу и поймет когда эта каша устарела или была скомпрометирована чем человек будет делать велосипед. Но я видимо ошибаюсь.

Comment: раз коснулись фреймворков... что лучше учить после чистого php? yii2 или laravel?

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать самому, можно перенести с другой машины, можно прицепить к HTTP трафику.

Самый простой способ зафиксировать авторизацию пользователя использовать сессии. Тогда у пользователя хранится только идентификатор сессии, а на сервере хранится статус авторизации.

Если сессии чем-то не устраивают, то можно реализовать аналогичный механизм

1. Генерируем некоторое случайное число
2. Записываем его в базу для этого пользователя. Там же в базу записываем время логина
3. Отсылаем пользователю две куки с идентификатором (как вариант - логином) пользователя и сгенерированное число.

При подключении пользователя проверяем

1. Есть ли нужные куки
2. Совпадают ли числа присланные пользователем и записанное в базе
3. Не истекло ли время логина.

Если все ОК - то пользователя пускаем, время логина и куки обновляем. MD5 хеши добавить по вкусу

Comment: Не подскажите где покопаться по поводу ограничений для просмотра части сайта? куда рыть? чем заменить эту куку?

Comment: @Дмитрий Написал примерный алгоритм

Comment: ИМХО, но лучше использовать строку, а не число, id сессии для её сброса и информацию о браузере пользователя.

Comment: ок, спасибо, попробуем реализовать.